# How to divide 2 and more emojii from 1 message telegram

Tags: telegram

```
{ message_id: 1326,
  from:
   { id: 346580048,
     is_bot: false,
     first_name: 'Andrey',
     last_name: 'Radkevich',
     username: 'andreyradkevich',
     language_code: 'uk-UA' },
  chat:
   { id: 346580048,
     first_name: 'Andrey',
     last_name: 'Radkevich',
     username: 'andreyradkevich',
     type: 'private' },
  date: 1520632810,
  text: '' }
```

how to divide all of this emoji from 1 telegram message ... I need to get all of this emojii and make 4 buttons in this example with each of this emoji which you can see in field text ..

Comment: What is your programming language?

Answer (score 0):

```
let GraphemeSplitter = require('grapheme-splitter');


// two-char emojis and six-char combined emoji
splitter.splitGraphemes("️‍"); // returns ["","","","","","️‍"]
```

https://github.com/orling/grapheme-splitter - answer you can find here